# VBA reads HTML from the old page after clicking submit button

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am not a programmer but I have managed to learn just a few things in VBA but now on a certain website I face a problem that does not exist on some other.

What should happen is that a page form should be completed with data, submit button clicked and then I want to get some data from the result page.

The first phase works fine but it seems that no matter what I do the VBA still reads data from the page before submit was clicked.

The code is:

```
Sub VIES2()

'Uruchomienie Internet Explorera i wstrzymanie dalszej akcji aż uzyska stan gotowości
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/?locale=pl"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'Wypełnienie formularza odpowiednimi wartościami i kliknięcie przycisku sprawdzenia
IE.document.getElementbyId("countryCombobox").Value = "IT"
IE.document.getElementbyId("number").Value = "01802840023"
IE.document.getElementbyId("requesterCountryCombobox").Value = "IT"
IE.document.getElementbyId("requesterNumber").Value = "01802840023"
IE.document.getElementbyId("submit").Click

'Test uzyskiwania opisu i identyfikatora zapytania

For t = 1 To 999999
Next t

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

For t = 1 To 999999
Next t

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

MsgBox IE.LocationURL

Set Text = IE.document.getElementsbyClassName("layout-content")

For Each Element In Text
MsgBox Element.innerText
Next

Set Test = IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("TABLE")

For Each Element In Test
MsgBox Element.innerText
Next

End Sub
```

I have tried putting break, various wait loops and Application.Wait as suggested in similar questions where it seems to have worked. Here, even after the page is long after fully loaded the code still reads the old page - at least pulling the URL and some data seems to point that it is the case.

UPDATE: I should also add that I have tried to make the macro refresh the page but it clears the input content. What is interesting that target URL is:

http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatResponse.html

If I change the initial page to this the browser instantly redirects to the original page with notification that initial data is needed. The macro then completes the data and clicks submit button. In this case IE.LocationURL indicates this URL:

http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatResponse.html

but according to the content I get with getElementsbyClassName still reads elements from the initial page:

http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/?locale=pl

Comment: What do you want to scrape from the target page?

Comment: The page verifies if given tax ID is an active one. In case of positive verification:
<span class="validStyle">Tak, numer VAT aktywny</span>
<td class="labelStyle">Identyfikator zapytania</td>
<td>WAPIAAAAWK-ftvgN</td>
In case of negative verification:
<span class="invalidStyle">Nieważny numer VAT dla transakcji transgranicznych w obrębie UE (<a href="faqvies.do">więcej informacji można znaleźć w „Najczęściej zadawanych pytaniach” – pytania 7, 11, 12, 13 i 20</a>).</span>

Comment: Why did you paste `html elements`? Just try to paste the portion of visible text. Btaw, I don't see any wait in your script when it comes across the new page.

Comment: Only this portion `Tak, numer VAT aktywny` or the tabular data connected to it as well? Because, I can see you have tried `tagname("table")` in your script.

Comment: Depending on the result the text "Tak, numer VAT aktywny" and then unique search identification number i.e.  "WAPIAAAAWK-iaFNr" or just Nieważny numer VAT dla transakcji transgranicznych w obrębie UE (więcej informacji można znaleźć w „Najczęściej zadawanych pytaniach” – pytania 7, 11, 12, 13 i 20). The script at this point is not aimed at the target content - initially I have just tried how to get to that (I am learning VBA) but realised that the content I am getting is completely different from what is actually displayed on the screen and in the HTML.

Comment: Try the solution provided by `QHarr`. It seems the script will do your job.

Comment: As for the wait section I have already deleted it earlier as it seemed useless. I have included it again just now but the result is the same. If I put a break into the code and wait long enough it is all the same as well.

Comment: Don't miss the edit. I've updated my answer with another alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although QHarr's solution is working in my end, I'm providing with another with no hardcoded delay within the script.

Using IE as your question was:

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, post As Object, elems As Object
    Dim elem As Object, r&, c&

    With New InternetExplorer
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/?locale=pl"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document

        With HTML
            .getElementById("countryCombobox").Value = "IT"
            .getElementById("number").Value = "01802840023"
            .getElementById("requesterCountryCombobox").Value = "IT"
            .getElementById("requesterNumber").Value = "01802840023"
            .getElementById("submit").Click

            Do: Set post = .getElementById("vatResponseFormTable"): DoEvents: Loop While post Is Nothing

            For Each elems In post.Rows
                For Each elem In elems.Cells
                    c = c + 1: Cells(r + 1, c) = elem.innerText
                Next elem
                c = 0: r = r + 1
            Next elems
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Using `xmlhttp` request (It is way faster than IE):

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim elems, elem As Object
    Dim QueryString$, S$, r&, c&

    QueryString = "memberStateCode=IT&number=01802840023&traderName=&traderStreet=&traderPostalCode=&traderCity=&requesterMemberStateCode=IT&requesterNumber=01802840023&action=check&check=Weryfikuj"

    With New XMLHTTP
        .Open "POST", "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatResponse.html", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send QueryString
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S

        For Each elems In .getElementById("vatResponseFormTable").Rows
            For Each elem In elems.Cells
                c = c + 1: Cells(r + 1, c) = elem.innerText
            Next elem
            c = 0: r = r + 1
        Next elems
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft XML, V6
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Nice. Plus one from me.

Comment: I generally answer these if I can but wait for you or tehscript/OmegaStripes to come along with a really good answer I can learn from. I am still struggling with the queryselector stuff you referred me to.

Comment: I'm really thrilled to know that you have already found out the giants I like most. `Tehscript` is one of my vba gurus who helps me a lot when in need.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you :) SIM for perfectly working solution and QHarr for leading me to an almost working solution - I still don't understand why on my end putting breaks or just confirmation text boxes is doing the trick in your code and mine as well and setting waiting points for as much as one minute is not :(

Answer (score 2):

This worked to print out the VAT response table

**Note:**

If on 32-bit remove the  `PtrSafe`.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Declare PtrSafe Sub sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwmilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub VIES2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim IE As Object

    'Uruchomienie Internet Explorera i wstrzymanie dalszej akcji az uzyska stan gotowosci
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/?locale=pl"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'Wypelnienie formularza odpowiednimi wartosciami i klikniecie przycisku sprawdzenia
    IE.document.getElementById("countryCombobox").Value = "IT"
    IE.document.getElementById("number").Value = "01802840023"
    IE.document.getElementById("requesterCountryCombobox").Value = "IT"
    IE.document.getElementById("requesterNumber").Value = "01802840023"
    IE.document.getElementById("submit").Click

    sleep (5000) 'or increase to 10000
    Dim tbl  As Object

    Set tbl = IE.document.getElementById("vatResponseFormTable")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws.Name = "Results"
    Dim rng As Range, currentRow As Object, currentColumn As Object, i As Long, outputRow As Long

        outputRow = outputRow + 1
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & outputRow)

        For Each currentRow In tbl.Rows
            For Each currentColumn In currentRow.Cells
                rng.Value = currentColumn.outerText
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                i = i + 1
            Next currentColumn
            outputRow = outputRow + 1
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -i)
            i = 0
        Next currentRow
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Did you try the above?

Comment: On my PC even with 10000 I get Run-time error '424' Object required. I assume that it means element with id "vatResponseFormTable" is missing. When I have added the part to display what is contained in class element "layout-content" it again shows all the stuff from previous page...

Comment: Did you try increasing the sleep time value ? You may have a slowly loading page. If you step through this with the code window at half size you should be able to monitor the events and see..

Comment: Yes I did. I have tried 50000 just now and unfortunately still nothing.

Comment: Any chance it has something to do with Excel/IE/OS version?

Comment: When you stepped through the code watching the IE window did you see the page load with the new information during the sleep line before pressing F8 to move on to  Dim tbl  As Object....

Comment: OK, now if I go step by step it gets the correct information. What is more interesting when I have deleted the sleep time altogether and go step by step very fast (definitely faster than the previous sleep time took) it still gets correct information.

Comment: How is that possible? If I set it to wait even for a minute it gets old data. If I go step by step and complete the whole process in 15 seconds it gets the correct data... I am very glad it finally works in one way or another and not that I complain but it is not meant to be executed from the code window :) How it operates now does not make sense to me, what is the logic here?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. But if simply commenting out the sleep does it that is a good thing. The key bit I changed was to target the table by ID and loop that.  Set tbl = IE.document.getElementById("vatResponseFormTable")

Comment: Yes, but commenting out the sleep does it only if I execute the code step by step. If I let it flow from the button press the result is incorrect. What is more when I have now tried my original code executed from the code window step by step it does work as well. If I run it lets say "freely" it gets the old data again...

Comment: Ahhhhh.........Well I am wondering if it has cached information now? So this still implies it is a timing issue doesn't it....hmmmmm...And why does it work perfectly for me? :-(

Comment: I have figured out something new. In my old code I am not starting it from the code window as in the excel I have multiple tax IDs and buttons next to them. Each button triggers macro with different data. So to run it step by step I have put multiple break points. Now I have started eliminating them one by one. Only one is left and the conclusion is that if I set it on the CLICK SUBMIT line and continue it is OK. If I set it just one line after the CLICK it is wrong. Amount of time I give it before continuing seems to have no impact on the result.

Comment: Have you added a DoEvents  in general outside of loop? It sounds like the code is ok but it is how the code sits in relation to the rest of your application code then?

Comment: Tested on your code as well and it is the same. Right now the fragment is:
`IE.document.getElementById("submit").Click
Dim tbl  As Object
Dim Text As Object
Dim Element As Object
MsgBox "OK"
Set Text = IE.document.getElementsbyClassName("layout-content")`
Break on CLICK works. Break on MsgBox and the old data is loaded.

Comment: That is just hilarious. I have added sleep (5000) before the CLICK and after the CLICK but before the MsgBox = OLD DATA. But if I again add the break at CLICK line and let it go instantly it is NEW DATA...

Comment: I admit defeat. I'm sorry :-(

Comment: Another update. I was a bit wrong, putting the break even before the CLICK i.e. in one of the lines that fill the form does the trick as well. Maybe the timing issue is somehow related to completing the form then. I don't see any relation to loading the new page here still...

Comment: One more question - Have you tried if my original code worked for you as well?

Comment: Well that's embarrassing but looks like your original solution also works for me. When I have had problems vaguely similar to this before, it has had to do with Caching and cached results being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you should search if there isn't a REST/SOAP available to achieve that kind of task.
Using an `Internet Explorer` instance for this is a total overkill.

Try this simple function, that uses the `SOAP` service to validate VAT numbers:

```
Function IsVatValid(country_code, vat_number)

Dim objHTTP         As Object
Dim xmlDoc          As Object

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
sURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService"

sEnv = "<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" & _
               "<s11:Body>" & _
                    "<tns1:checkVat xmlns:tns1='urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types'>" & _
                    "<tns1:countryCode>" & country_code & "</tns1:countryCode>" & _
                    "<tns1:vatNumber>" & vat_number & "</tns1:vatNumber>" & _
                    "</tns1:checkVat>" & _
               "</s11:Body>" & _
               "</s11:Envelope>"


objHTTP.Open "Post", sURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "checkVatService"
objHTTP.send (sEnv)
objHTTP.waitForResponse

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
xmlDoc.body.innerHTML = objHTTP.responsetext

IsVatValid = CBool(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("valid")(0).innerHTML)

Set xmlDoc = Nothing
Set objHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

And then you can simply validate all your vat numbers:

```
Debug.Print IsVatValid("IT", "01802840023")
>>> True
```

Comment: This is new and exciting to me.....any references on where I can find examples of this being used with VBA or a decent tutorial to understand the principals please?

Comment: @QHarr I am not sure what you mean by 'understand the principals' ? You can think of`SOAP` as a `REST API`, except for the fact the you need to post XML data to the webservice, hence the need to build the string.

Comment: Many thanks drec4s - yes I suspected that it is not the best way to do this, but I have no IT experience and just started experiments and trying to find out what can be done with VBA - even possibility to launch IE and manipulate IE was exciting and for my needs it worked in another case and I was wondering why wouldn't it here.

Comment: You also need to check the accepted xml schema for that particular webservice.

Comment: I have no IT background as well, just started with vba some years ago and have been enjoying the journey ;)

Comment: @Tred if any of the answers solved your problem, please consider marking it as correct, so it can be of help to others as well.